# How to change php-cli Version (Wamp)

Tags: wamp, php

I have since a long time a wamp installation with php 5.3.5
Now I'm working with Symfony2.1, and need intl extension 
So I downloaded & installed php 5.4.6 and things worked fine in a first time

But now I'm on a new project where I need to install via the php console (php-cli) some required bundles.
One of this bundles is sonata-project/intl-bundle
when asking for update by "php composer.phar update"
I get error messages that seems to say that the intl extension is not installed

After some Googleing I understand that my php-cli version is still 5.3.5
So I tried to change my windows XP environmental variable PATH and replaced the 5.3.5 path by the 5.4.6 path
But now I get the following error on the dos console :

```
Failed loading c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.5/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.3-vc6.dll
PHP 5.4.6 (cli) (built: Aug 15 2012 21:16:03)</br>
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group</br>
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies</br>
```

is there anyone who can help me fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above looks to be a conflict with your php.ini. Are both 5.4.6 and 5.3.5 both using the same php.ini file?

If this is the case, 5.4.6 does not have the xdebug extension installed, or, more likely it 5.4.6 is using a newer API version leading to an incompatibility issue. Remove the xdebug clause form your php.ini file and rerun.

Comment: Ok I removed the xdebug clause
Now I get a windows  error :
php.exe - Point d'entrée introuvable
Le point d'entrée de procédure output_globals_id est introuvable dans la bibliothèque de liaisons dynamique php5ts.dll


But after clicking OK on this error the PHP continues :
Failed loading c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.5/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.1.0-5.3-vc6.dll
PHP 5.4.6 (cli) (built: Aug 15 2012 21:16:03)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

Answer (score 8):

You need to add your PHP installation directory to the %PATH% environment variable. It is usually something like `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.4` or work from the PHP installation directory.

Answer (score 6):

In windows 10, You must update the PHP path in the environment variable section for the system not only the user. It would work well after that...

Good luck.

[image]

Comment: I tried path, Wamp->php->version, reboot -- still nothing helped to PowerShell. I continue using old version :(